# ROS installation on intel edison

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting following error while installing ROS on intel edison with UbiLinux. Following these steps for installation http://wiki.ros.org/wiki/edison

```
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:380:43: error: macro "BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp: In member function ‘ros::CallbackQueue::CallOneResult ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*)’:
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_`enter code here`comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:380:7: error: ‘BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:381:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:384:7: error: ‘struct boost::scope_exit::aux::undeclared’ has no member named ‘value’
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:384:7: error: ‘boost_se_guard_384’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:398:9: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp: At global scope:

    /home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:408:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
    /home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:413:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
    /home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:416:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    root@ubilinux:/home/edison/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257349/ros-installation-on-intel-edison/) by [Mrutyunjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/29747/mrutyunjay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

edit: I've been working through this on my beaglebone board throughout the day and actually couldn't push this all the way through. I'm going to leave my earlier reply in case it's helpful to someone, but it was easier for me to just upgrade my distro to jessie and just install kinetic...

---

I believe the problem here is that the ros install depends on c++11 features which are not available on your device. I solved this exact problem (on a beagleebone running wheezy) by adding this flag to the build command:

`--cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=--std=c++0x`

I also needed to upgrade my boost library to 1.53 to get the entire install to complete. See http://yplam.com/ros/2017/03/19/edison-ros-install.html as well

---

Originally posted by [emef](https://answers.ros.org/users/29888/emef/) with karma: 41 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-31**:
Do you mean boost 1.53 ?

**Comment by [emef](https://answers.ros.org/users/29888/emef/) on 2017-03-31**:
yep, fixed

**Comment by [dlheard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29891/dlheard/) on 2017-03-31**:
What was the build command that you added this flag to?

**Comment by [emef](https://answers.ros.org/users/29888/emef/) on 2017-03-31**:
`./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo`